# Folder Lock not working

Tags: windows

I downloaded `Folderlock 7` and installed it on Windows. When I drag and drop the folders that I want to lock, the software shows it is locked but the folders are still visible in the directory which shouldn't be the case once a file/folder has been locked. I reinstalled the software which the illusion that it might solve this problem but the problem is still there.

How can I solve this problem?

Regards

Comment: Tried `Run as Administrator`?

Comment: yes. I did that already